# 301 Redirects and Merchant center quality

Tags: 301-redirect, google-ads, shopping

I moved a site to a new platform and the url structure was updated. As far as the Google Merchant Center goes will the 301 redirects suffice or do I need to update my urls within merchant center?

Comment: As long as all the links are redirecting correctly, you should be fine. They will eventually get updated on google automatically to the new links.